# What would be the effect of a non-periapsis and non-apoapsis prograde burn on the shape of an objects orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, orbital

Pretty new to orbital mechanics and this question has been bugging me. How would the shape of the orbit be affected by a prograde burn at a location that isn't the periapsis or apoapsis ? For example at the arbitarary ***A*** below

[image: Eliptical Orbit]

In particular that would be the effect on the orientation of the major axis and the distances of the periapsis and apoasis.

Thanks !

Comment: You should play Kerbal Space Program to get a feeling for this, but I won't take any responsibility for a significant increase of your procrastination level.

Comment: There is a simpler program for mobile called Simple Rockets that can demonstrate this, too. Loads of fun.

Comment: Are you looking for more detail other than that the section of the orbit generally opposite the burn is raised, while the point at which the burn occurs remains unchanged?

Comment: Apoapsis also shifts in the direction of the point-opposite-burn, while periapsis shifts towards the burn point.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Thanks for the input , I suspected the shift would be what you described. And not to get super needy but some math to back it up would be swell if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @koalo Thanks, I was going to buy it the other day but I already have enough trouble getting stuff done.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule of thumb, any prograde or retrograde burn establishes a new orbit tangent to the old orbit at the point of the burn.  A prograde burn increases the length of the major axis, while a retrograde burn reduces it.  To demonstrate, I set up a situation similar to yours in Kerbal Space Program, and had it draw the results of two proposed maneuvers.  In both, the solid blue-green line is the initial orbit, the dotted brown line is the the result of the maneuver, and the star shape is the point of the burn.

[image]

A prograde burn at your proposed "point A" extends the major axis, raising both the periapsis and apoapsis, and rotating the major axis in the prograde direction.

[image]

A prograde burn on the other side of the orbit's major axis also raises the periapsis and apoapsis, but rotates the major axis in the other direction.